# create website without an home page

Tags: php, html, seo

I would like to create a website without an home page

example for home page will be 
www.lawyer.com

instead i would like to present only clean urls like this 
www.lawyer.com/lawyer-in-us-chicago
www.lawyer.com/lawyer-in-us-denver
etc...

my first question is 
how will it affect on my SEO?

do i must have an home page like
www.lawyer.com
even if i don't have any content to put on it

my second question is
how should i redirect from
www.lawyer.com to www.lawyer.com/chicago-lawyers

Comment: research mod-rewrite

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just put a blank page called `index.html`, and inside it write the following JavaScript code (inside `<script></script>` tag):

```
window.location.href = "www.lawyer.com/chicago-lawyers";
```